# Multiple Groupings with left join not working

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

I'm trying to solve this problem for days, but am not succeeding. I hope for your expertise:

The **grouping I want to achieve**, also at: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuMqw.jpg
[image]

Sample available at **sqlfiddle**: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e42e6/2

**The DDL and sample data**:

```
CREATE TABLE tx_management_domain_model_events (
    `uid` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `title` varchar(255),
    PRIMARY KEY(uid)
);

CREATE TABLE tx_management_domain_model_programm (
    `uid` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `jobtype` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    `reservation` int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    `eventdate` date NULL,
    `event` int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(uid)
);

CREATE TABLE tx_management_domain_model_reservations (
    `uid` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `event` int(11) default '0',
    `feuser` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
    `status` int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    `ressource` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY(uid)
);

CREATE TABLE tx_management_domain_model_appointments (
    `uid` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `begin` int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    `end` int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    `event` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(uid)
);

CREATE TABLE tx_management_domain_model_additionalcosts (
    `uid` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `additionalcosttype` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    `event` int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    `feuser` int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    `reservation` int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (uid)
);

CREATE TABLE tx_management_domain_model_referents (
    `uid` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `specialsallary` text NULL,
    `feuser` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    `event` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,  
    PRIMARY KEY(uid)
);

CREATE TABLE fe_users (
    `uid` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `fullname` varchar(255),
    PRIMARY KEY(uid)
);

# ---------------------- Fill with data --------------------
INSERT INTO tx_management_domain_model_events
    (`uid`, `title`)
VALUES
    (1660, 'Event-1'),
    (1632, 'Event-2');

INSERT INTO tx_management_domain_model_programm
    (`uid`, `jobtype`, `reservation`, `event`, `eventdate`)
VALUES
    (1149, 2, 11259, 1660, '2015-05-04'),
    (1154, 0, 11278, 1660, '2015-05-04'),
    (1534, 0, 11783, 1660, '2015-07-11');

INSERT INTO tx_management_domain_model_reservations
    (`uid`, `event`, `feuser`, `status`, `ressource`)
VALUES
    (11259, 1660, 116740, 1105, 19901),
    (11278, 1660, 116740, 1105, 19901),
    (11280, 1660, 117354, 1101, 19902),
    (11783, 1660, 116740, 1101, 19901),
    (11784, 1660, 116740, 1101, 100001);

INSERT INTO tx_management_domain_model_appointments
    (`uid`, `begin`, `end`, `event`)
VALUES
    (1104, 1430690400, 1432936800, 1660),
    (1123, 1436565600, 1436652000, 1660),
    (1127, 1436306400, 1436911200, 1632);

INSERT INTO tx_management_domain_model_additionalcosts
    (`uid`, `additionalcosttype`, `event`, `feuser`, `reservation`)
VALUES
    (1, 0, 1660, 11740, 11784);

INSERT INTO tx_management_domain_model_referents
    (`uid`, `specialsallary`, `feuser`, `event`)
VALUES
    (1885, '', 116740, 1660),
    (1935, '', 116740, 1632);

INSERT INTO fe_users
    (`uid`, `fullname`)
VALUES
    (116740, 'John Kohn');
```

**SQL-Query**:

```
select
    group_concat(distinct tbl_events.uid) as Event,
    date_format(from_unixtime(tbl_appointments.`begin`),get_format(DATE, 'EUR')) AS 'appointmentBegin',
    date_format(from_unixtime(tbl_appointments.`end`),get_format(DATE, 'EUR')) AS 'appointmentEnd',
    group_concat(distinct tbl_reservations.ressource) as Ressource,
    group_concat(distinct tbl_programm.jobtype) as Jobtyp,
    group_concat(tbl_reservations.uid) AS Reservations,
    group_concat(distinct tbl_referents.specialsallary) AS Specialsallary
from 
    tx_management_domain_model_events tbl_events
    inner join tx_management_domain_model_reservations as tbl_reservations on tbl_reservations.event = tbl_events.uid
    inner join tx_management_domain_model_appointments as tbl_appointments on tbl_events.uid = tbl_appointments.event
    left join tx_management_domain_model_programm as tbl_programm on tbl_reservations.uid = tbl_programm.reservation and tbl_programm.eventdate between from_unixtime(tbl_appointments.`begin`) and from_unixtime(tbl_appointments.`end`)
    left join tx_management_domain_model_additionalcosts as tbl_additionalcosts on tbl_reservations.uid = tbl_additionalcosts.reservation
    inner join fe_users on tbl_reservations.feuser = fe_users.uid
    inner join tx_management_domain_model_referents as tbl_referents on tbl_reservations.feuser = tbl_referents.feuser
where tbl_reservations.feuser = 116740
    and tbl_reservations.ressource in (19901,19902,100001,100002)
    and tbl_referents.event = tbl_events.uid
    and tbl_programm.event = tbl_events.uid
group by
    tbl_events.uid,
    CASE WHEN (tbl_reservations.ressource in (19901,19902,100001,100002) AND ((tbl_referents.specialsallary IS NULL) OR (tbl_referents.specialsallary LIKE ''))) THEN tbl_reservations.ressource ELSE tbl_referents.specialsallary END,
    from_unixtime(tbl_appointments.`begin`),
    from_unixtime(tbl_appointments.`end`),
    tbl_programm.jobtype;
```

**Problem**: None of the records in tx_management_domain_model_additionalcosts is shown.

**Expected**: The reservation "11784" should also be in the result-column "Reservations".

**Hint**: If I comment out each WHERE-condition for tbl_programm, then the record of tbl_additionalcosts is shown. But why do I have to remove these conditions?

Does anyone see where I'm having a bug?

Comment: You should include the sample data and desired results in your question.  Stack Overflow questions should not depend on other web sites to make sense.

Comment: What shall I include here? As you can see it's too much data

Comment: If it is too much data, then you did not reduce your problem to the core. Minimize your example to something simple. We want questions be useful to future visitors too that need to understand quickly if they have the same problem as you. So try to generalize your problem

Comment: Sorry, I can't cope with your naming policy

Comment: However, note that `CASE WHEN (r.ressource in (19901,19902,100001,100002)` is redundant because r.ressource is always one of those codes... and `LEFT JOIN programm... WHERE programm...` = `INNER JOIN  programm... WHERE programm`

Comment: No. r.ressource is not always one of those codes. There are also other codes, which I haven't used because they don't play a role for grouping.

Answer (score 0):

One of your condition inside the where clause is excluding he reservation "11784" see below it is isolated.

```
select
    tbl_reservations.uid
from 
    tx_management_domain_model_events tbl_events
    inner join tx_management_domain_model_reservations as tbl_reservations on tbl_reservations.event = tbl_events.uid
    inner join tx_management_domain_model_appointments as tbl_appointments on tbl_events.uid = tbl_appointments.event
    left join tx_management_domain_model_programm as tbl_programm on tbl_reservations.uid = tbl_programm.reservation and tbl_programm.eventdate between from_unixtime(tbl_appointments.`begin`) and from_unixtime(tbl_appointments.`end`)
    left join tx_management_domain_model_additionalcosts as tbl_additionalcosts on tbl_reservations.uid = tbl_additionalcosts.reservation
    inner join fe_users on tbl_reservations.feuser = fe_users.uid
    inner join tx_management_domain_model_referents as tbl_referents on tbl_reservations.feuser = tbl_referents.feuser
where tbl_reservations.feuser = 116740
    and tbl_reservations.ressource in (19901,19902,100001,100002)

    /* JOIN */
    and tbl_referents.event = tbl_events.uid

    /* JOIN & this condition excludes "11784"*/
    and tbl_programm.event = tbl_events.uid

order by
    tbl_reservations.uid
```

Note that predicate, and the one before it are both JOINING not filtering
SO, my suggestion would be to move both of those into the FROM clause

**Result**

```
| Event | appointmentBegin | appointmentEnd | Ressource | Jobtyp | Reservations | Specialsallary |
|-------|------------------|----------------|-----------|--------|--------------|----------------|
|  1660 |       03.05.2015 |     29.05.2015 |    100001 | (null) |        11784 |                |
|  1660 |       10.07.2015 |     11.07.2015 |    100001 | (null) |        11784 |                |
|  1660 |       03.05.2015 |     29.05.2015 |     19901 | (null) |        11783 |                |
|  1660 |       03.05.2015 |     29.05.2015 |     19901 |      0 |        11278 |                |
|  1660 |       03.05.2015 |     29.05.2015 |     19901 |      2 |        11259 |                |
|  1660 |       10.07.2015 |     11.07.2015 |     19901 | (null) |  11259,11278 |                |
|  1660 |       10.07.2015 |     11.07.2015 |     19901 |      0 |        11783 |                |
```

**By Modified Query**

```
select
    group_concat(distinct tbl_events.uid) as Event,
    date_format(from_unixtime(tbl_appointments.`begin`),get_format(DATE, 'EUR')) AS 'appointmentBegin',
    date_format(from_unixtime(tbl_appointments.`end`),get_format(DATE, 'EUR')) AS 'appointmentEnd',
    group_concat(distinct tbl_reservations.ressource) as Ressource,
    group_concat(distinct tbl_programm.jobtype) as Jobtyp,
    group_concat(tbl_reservations.uid) AS Reservations,
    group_concat(distinct tbl_referents.specialsallary) AS Specialsallary
from 
    tx_management_domain_model_events tbl_events
    inner join tx_management_domain_model_reservations as tbl_reservations on tbl_reservations.event = tbl_events.uid
    inner join tx_management_domain_model_appointments as tbl_appointments on tbl_events.uid = tbl_appointments.event
    left join tx_management_domain_model_programm as tbl_programm on tbl_reservations.uid = tbl_programm.reservation and tbl_programm.eventdate between from_unixtime(tbl_appointments.`begin`) and from_unixtime(tbl_appointments.`end`)
    and tbl_programm.event = tbl_events.uid

    left join tx_management_domain_model_additionalcosts as tbl_additionalcosts on tbl_reservations.uid = tbl_additionalcosts.reservation
    inner join fe_users on tbl_reservations.feuser = fe_users.uid
    inner join tx_management_domain_model_referents as tbl_referents on tbl_reservations.feuser = tbl_referents.feuser
    and tbl_referents.event = tbl_events.uid

where tbl_reservations.feuser = 116740
    and tbl_reservations.ressource in (19901,19902,100001,100002)
group by
    tbl_events.uid,
    CASE WHEN (tbl_reservations.ressource in (19901,19902,100001,100002) AND ((tbl_referents.specialsallary IS NULL) OR (tbl_referents.specialsallary LIKE ''))) THEN tbl_reservations.ressource ELSE tbl_referents.specialsallary END,
    from_unixtime(tbl_appointments.`begin`),
    from_unixtime(tbl_appointments.`end`),
    tbl_programm.jobtype;
```

**Note:** IF you include predicates in the where clause of tables joined by an outer join, you can very easily override the effect of that outer join so in effect it becomes an inner join.

Comment: Thanks for your tip. It was really the problem. But now, as you can see we have a different problem:  We get multiple records / lines for the "additionalcost"-record for each appointment of the event -> What I wanted to achieve is: Only 1 record for additionalcost, as it has no appointments. The problems are: 1) "additionalcosts" gets connected to appointments, as appointments are connected with event, which is also connected with additionalcost 2) We have no limitation like we have with "program->eventdate". Therefore we get all appointment-records for additionalcosts

How could we do that?

Comment: "as you can see ..." but I do not see this. Don't assume we are familiar with your data and requirements (because we are not). I believe I have answered the original question, but sounds like you now have a new question.

Comment: ok, perhaps I see more of what you mean now, but I don't know your needs well enough to suggest an immediate solution. you need more case expressions probably. can you just exclude **appointmentBegin & appointmentEnd** from the select and grouping clauses?

Comment: No I can't remove. I need them.

Comment: Well you have to do something about them if you also want fewer rows

Comment: I cannot read minds through a browser, sorry. Take the min/max perhaps? Use case expressions inside the min/max functions? I am just informing you what the impediment is.